# Remove Gesture for view while Sliding Menu Activated

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, ecslidingviewcontroller

i'm using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) and i've a problem when using pan Gesture to open the sliding menu the tableview in the main view still have the scrolling gesture

i need to remove the gesture of the main view and add it back when it slide back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the InitViewController add the following method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return NO;
}
```

if return YES it will make the undesirable behavior

Comment: What happens if you return `YES` here? Which gesture is this delegate method for? You might have to return `YES` for both the `panGesture` and the table's scroll gesture.